# Solr 5 - Restrict access to specific IP

Tags: solr, solrj, solr5

Due to security reasons, I wish to restrict access to Solr server to particular IP's only. Since Solr 5 runs as a standalone server, could someone please let me know how can I do this restriction.

I did try searching for a solution, but all I could come up with were solutions related to Solr 4 and previous versions in which Solr war was deployed in containers and not standalone.

Thanks in advance !!!

Comment: Could you not implement this policy at a network level (eg on a router/switch)?

Comment: But there should be a way of restricting unauthorized access to solr servers. I have other applications running on this server, hence would prefer not to do this at the router/switch level.

Comment: Fair comment - though you can also restrict ports so that only solr would be affected ... BUT, i totally repect that you are looking for the RIGHT answer. Good luck :0)